# JavaScript Array of Custom HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension to manage my YouTube subscriptions. I am trying to create a JavaScript array of all of the elements in the image, between the red lines. The problem is, for some reason, Youtube is using multiple IDs with the name "items" so I can't just use a simple $("items").children().

[image]

The closest I have managed to get is to the #sections div (shown in blue) by using:

```
$('div#guide-inner-content ytd-guide-renderer#guide-renderer div#sections');
```

But when I attempt to go further into the element by using .children() at the end and try to console.log it, it doesn't seem to work at all and just returns an empty jQuery object. I figured the issue may be due to the fact that the child elements are strange, custom elements `<ytd-guide-section-renderer>` elements) instead of regular `<div>` elements.

What is another method I could use to get all of the `<ytd-guide-entry-renderer>` elements inside the red lines and store them in an array?

Comment: How about `$("ytd-guide-entry-renderer")`?

Comment: jQuery should treat all elements the same. If those elements are added dynamically, they might not exist when your code is running.

Comment: have you tried this: document.getElementsByTagName("ytd-guide-entry-renderer");, returns a list of all elements with the specific tag name

Comment: After giving that a quick try, it seems to be doing the same thing as when I attempted to add .children(). It just returns an empty jQuery object.

Comment: Regarding if they are added dynamically, would there be any way at all for me to access them?

Comment: It turns out the elements were dynamically being loaded and I was attempting to access them before they existed. I fixed this by adding a `setTimeout(function() {}, 1000);` 1 second delay to give time for the elements to load before attempting to access them. After the 1 second passed all of the answers everyone provided worked to some extent.